# Is Quasi-Likelihood As "Strong" As The Standard Likelihood?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, quasi-likelihood

I have been trying to learn more about the differences between Quasi Likelihood compared to the standard Likelihood. When learning about this, the following points come to mind:

- The Quasi-Likelihood Method is said to be able to provide estimates that are consistent even when the Variance Function is misspecified - but is there a limit to how misspecified the Variance Function can be? For example - if I choose to deliberately misspecify the Variance Function in a very significant way (e.g. arbitrary combination of trigonometric polynomials) - will the Quasi-Likelihood Method still provide consistent estimates? Surely this is not the case - there must be some reasonable thresholds that limit the degree to which this can be true?
- It seems like estimates derived from the Quasi-Likelihood Method have similar statistical properties to the estimates derived from the Non-Quasi Likelihood Method - yet the Quasi-Likelihood Method has the added benefit of producing desirable estimates for Variance Functions not supported by the Exponential Family, as well as guaranteeing that these estimates maintain these desirable statistical properties. Does this mean that the Quasi-Likelihood Method can at least be considered equal to the standard Likelihood Method in the worst-case scenario, but also have the ability to be considered "better" (e.g. more versatile)?

Can someone please comment on this?